# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option when creating tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

This script is supposed to create three tables: proyecto, empleados, tareas. However, everytime I try to run it in Oracle Database Express Edition, I get the error message. What could be the problem? There is no error when I just run the part of the code that creates each table.

```
CREATE TABLE proyectos (
id_proyecto INTEGER NOT NULL,
nombre_proyecto VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
fecha_inicio DATE NOT NULL,
fecha_fin_tentativa DATE NOT NULL,
fecha_fin_real DATE
)
/
ALTER TABLE proyectos ADD CONSTRAINT proyectos_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_proyecto)
/
ALTER TABLE proyectos ADD CONSTRAINT proyectos_uk UNIQUE (nombre_proyecto)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE proyectos_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 40
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_proyectos
BEFORE INSERT
ON proyectos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.id_proyecto IS NULL
THEN
    SELECT proyectos_seq.NEXTVAL
        INTO :NEW.id_proyecto
        FROM DUAL;
END IF;
END;
/
COMMENT ON TABLE proyectos IS 'Todos los proyectos en desarrollo.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN proyectos.id_proyecto IS 'Llave primaria generada por el sistema.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN proyectos.nombre_proyecto IS 'Nombre unico del proyecto.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN proyectos.fecha_inicio IS 'Fecha de inicio del proyecto.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN proyectos.fecha_fin_tentativa IS 'Fecha tentativa de terminacion del proyecto.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN proyectos.fecha_fin_real IS 'Fecha real de terminacion del proyecto.'
/
INSERT INTO proyectos
            (id_proyecto, nombre_proyecto, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin_tentativa)
    VALUES (1, 'Infraestructura interna', SYSDATE - 150, SYSDATE - 30)
/
INSERT INTO proyectos
            (id_proyecto, nombre_proyecto, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin_tentativa)
    VALUES (2, 'Nuevo sistema de nomina', SYSDATE - 150, SYSDATE + 15)
/
INSERT INTO proyectos
            (id_proyecto, nombre_proyecto, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin_tentativa)
    VALUES (3, 'Integracion de Email', SYSDATE - 120, SYSDATE - 60)
/
INSERT INTO proyectos
            (id_proyecto, nombre_proyecto, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin_tentativa)
    VALUES (4, 'Sitio web', SYSDATE - 60, SYSDATE + 30)
/
INSERT INTO proyectos
            (id_proyecto, nombre_proyecto, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin_tentativa)
    VALUES (5, 'Encuesta de satisfaccion de los empleados', SYSDATE - 30, SYSDATE + 60)
/
--
-- empleados
--
-- Crea la tabla de empleados
-- Implementa una llave foranea para validar que el
-- empleado este asignado a un proyecto valido
-- Implementa un CHECK para asegurarse que todo lider o miembro de proyecto este asignado a un proyecto
--
CREATE TABLE empleados (
id_empleado INTEGER NOT NULL,
nombre_empleado VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
email_empleado VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
rol_empleado VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
proyecto_asignado INTEGER
)
/
ALTER TABLE empleados ADD CONSTRAINT empleados_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_empleado)
/
ALTER TABLE empleados ADD CONSTRAINT empleados_uk UNIQUE (nombre_empleado)
/
ALTER TABLE empleados ADD CONSTRAINT empleados_role_cc CHECK (rol_empleado IN ('Gerente','Administrador','Lider','Miembro'))
/
ALTER TABLE empleados ADD CONSTRAINT empleados_project_fk FOREIGN KEY (proyecto_asignado) REFERENCES proyectos
/
ALTER TABLE empleados ADD CONSTRAINT empleados_assignment_cc
CHECK ( (rol_empleado IN ('Lider','Miembro') AND proyecto_asignado IS NOT NULL)
OR (rol_empleado IN ('Gerente','Administrador') AND proyecto_asignado IS NULL) )
/
CREATE SEQUENCE empleados_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 40
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_empleados
BEFORE INSERT
ON empleados
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.id_empleado IS NULL
THEN
    SELECT empleados_seq.NEXTVAL
        INTO :NEW.id_empleado
        FROM DUAL;
END IF;
END;
/
COMMENT ON TABLE empleados IS 'Todos los empleados de la compa�ia.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN empleados.id_empleado IS 'Llave primaria generada por el sistema.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN empleados.nombre_empleado IS 'Nombre unico del empleado.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN empleados.rol_empleado IS 'El rol del empleado.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN empleados.proyecto_asignado IS 'El proyecto al que se encuentra actualmente asignado.'
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (1, 'Joe Cerno', 'joe.cerno@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Gerente', NULL)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (2, 'Kim Roberts', 'kim.roberts@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Administrador', NULL)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (3, 'Tom Suess', 'tom.suess@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Administrador', NULL)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (4, 'Al Bines', 'al.bines@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Lider', 1)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (5, 'Carla Downing', 'carla.downing@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Lider', 2)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (6, 'Evan Fanner', 'evan.fanner@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Lider', 3)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (7, 'George Hurst', 'george.hurst@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Lider', 4)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (8, 'Irene Jones', 'irene.jones@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Lider', 5)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (9, 'Karen London', 'karen.london@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Miembro', 1)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (10, 'Mark Nile', 'mark.nile@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Miembro', 1)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (11, 'Jane Kerry', 'jane.kerry@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Miembro', 5)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (12, 'Olive Pope', 'olive.pope@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Miembro', 2)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (13, 'Russ Sanders', 'russ.sanders@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Miembro', 3)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (14, 'Tucker Uberton', 'tucker.uberton@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Miembro', 3)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (15, 'Vicky Williams', 'vicky.willaims@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Miembro', 4)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (16, 'Scott Tiger', 'scott.tiger@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Miembro', 4)
/
INSERT INTO empleados
            (id_empleado, nombre_empleado, email_empleado, rol_empleado, proyecto_asignado)
    VALUES (17, 'Yvonne Zeiring', 'yvonee.zeiring@mrvl-bademail.com', 'Miembro', 4)
/
--
-- TAREAS
--
-- Implementa una llave foranea para validar que la tarea este asignada a un empleado v�lido
-- Otra para validar el proyecto
-- Implementa un CHECK para validar el eestatus
-- Otro para validar la prioridad
-- Implementa una secuencia para generar el ID y la fecha de creacion, el usuario
-- que crea la tarea y asigna el eestatus de Activo si no se provee un eestatus
-- Graba la fecha y el usuario que hace la modificaci�n y si se di�
-- "fecha de terminaci�n real" pone el eestatus en "Terminado"
--

CREATE TABLE tareas (
id_tarea INTEGER NOT NULL,
descrip_corta_tarea VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
descrip_detallada_tarea VARCHAR2(2000),
identificada_por INTEGER NOT NULL,
identificada_fecha DATE NOT NULL,
proyecto_relacionado INTEGER NOT NULL,
asignada_a INTEGER,
estatus VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL,
prioridad VARCHAR2(6),
fecha_fin_tentativa DATE,
progreso VARCHAR2(2000),
fecha_fin_real DATE,
resumen_solucion VARCHAR2(2000),
fecha_creacion DATE NOT NULL,
creada_por VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
fecha_ultima_modificacion DATE,
usuario_ultima_modificacion VARCHAR2(60)
)
/
ALTER TABLE tareas ADD CONSTRAINT tareas_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_tarea)
/
ALTER TABLE tareas ADD CONSTRAINT tareas_identificada_por_fk FOREIGN KEY (identificada_por) REFERENCES empleados
/
ALTER TABLE tareas ADD CONSTRAINT tareas_asignada_a_fk FOREIGN KEY (asignada_a) REFERENCES empleados
/
ALTER TABLE tareas ADD CONSTRAINT tareas_project_fk FOREIGN KEY (proyecto_relacionado) REFERENCES proyectos
/
ALTER TABLE tareas ADD CONSTRAINT tareas_estatus_cc CHECK (estatus IN ('Activa','En pausa','Terminada'))
/
ALTER TABLE tareas ADD CONSTRAINT tareas_prioridad_cc CHECK (prioridad IN ('Alta','Media','Baja'))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE tareas_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 40
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_tareas
BEFORE INSERT
ON tareas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.id_tarea IS NULL
THEN
    SELECT tareas_seq.NEXTVAL
        INTO :NEW.id_tarea
        FROM DUAL;
END IF;

IF :NEW.estatus IS NULL
THEN
    :NEW.estatus := 'Activa';
END IF;

:NEW.fecha_creacion := SYSDATE;
:NEW.creada_por := NVL(wwv_flow.g_user, USER);
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bu_tareas
BEFORE UPDATE
ON tareas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.fecha_fin_real IS NOT NULL
THEN
    :NEW.estatus := 'Terminada';
END IF;

:NEW.fecha_ultima_modificacion := SYSDATE;
:NEW.usuario_ultima_modificacion := NVL(wwv_flow.g_user, USER);
END;
/
COMMENT ON TABLE tareas IS 'Todas las tareas asignadas a los proyectos.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.id_tarea IS 'La llave primaria generada por el sistema.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.descrip_corta_tarea IS 'Breve resumen de la tarea.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.descrip_detallada_tarea IS 'Descripcion detallada de la tarea.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.identificada_por IS 'El empleado que identifico la tarea.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.identificada_fecha IS 'La fecha de identificacion.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.proyecto_relacionado IS 'El proyecto al que esta relacionada la tarea.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.asignada_a IS 'El empleado a quien se le asigno la tarea.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.estatus IS 'El estatus actual de la tarea.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.prioridad IS 'La prioridad de la tarea, esto es, cuan importante es.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.fecha_fin_tentativa IS 'La fecha en que se planea tener resuelta la tarea.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.fecha_fin_real IS 'La fecha en que se resolvio realmente.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.progreso IS 'Cualquier nota indicando el progreso.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.resumen_solucion IS 'Una descripcion de como fue resuelta la tarea.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.fecha_creacion IS 'Columna de auditoria: Fecha de alta del registro.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.creada_por IS 'Columna de auditoria: Usuario que dio de alta del registro.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.fecha_ultima_modificacion IS 'Columna de auditoria: Fecha de ultima modificacion.'
/
COMMENT ON COLUMN tareas.usuario_ultima_modificacion IS 'Columna de auditoria: El usuario que la modifico por ultima vez.'
/
--
-- Integracion de Email
--
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (1, 'Los servidores no tienen servicios de respaldo debido a un incendio en la planta Norte', '', 6, SYSDATE - 80, 3, 6, 'Terminada', 'Media', SYSDATE - 73, 'Realizando implementacion.', SYSDATE - 73, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (2, 'Retrasos en el envio de correo entre servidores en espejo', '', 6, SYSDATE - 100, 3, 14, 'Activa', 'Baja', SYSDATE - 80, '', '', '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (3, 'Algunas propuestas de los proveedores de servicios no han sido analizadas', '', 6, SYSDATE - 110, 3, 13, 'Terminada', 'Media', SYSDATE - 90, '', SYSDATE - 95, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (4, 'Las licencias del software en la planta Oeste estan por expirar', '', 1, SYSDATE - 70, 3, 6, 'Terminada', 'Alta', SYSDATE - 60, '', SYSDATE - 66, 'Se trabajo con el equipo de sistemas de la planta y se aplico un parche.')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (5, 'Implementar actualizaciones en la planta Norte', '', 1, SYSDATE - 100, 3, 13, 'Terminada', 'Alta', SYSDATE - 90, '', SYSDATE - 95, 'Se trabajo con el equipo de sistemas de la planta y se aplico el parche.')
/
--
-- Encuesta de satisfaccion de los empleados
--
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (6, 'Revision con los directivos', '', 8, SYSDATE - 30, 5, NULL, 'Terminada', 'Media', SYSDATE - 15, '', SYSDATE - 20, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (7, 'Distribuir traducciones al ingles para las plantas en Estados Unidos', '', 8, SYSDATE - 2, 5, 8, 'Activa', 'Media', SYSDATE + 10, 'En revision ortografica y gramatical', '', '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (8, 'Proveer ayuda en linea para preguntas frecuentes', '', 1, SYSDATE - 10, 5, 11, 'Activa', 'Media', SYSDATE + 20, '', '', '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (9, 'Se necesitan definiciones mas claras en la seccion de departamentos y roles', '', 1, SYSDATE - 8, 5, NULL, 'Activa', 'Baja', SYSDATE + 15, '', '', '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (10, 'De acuerdo al asesor legal se requieren definiciones mas aplias para los servicios de salud otorgados', '', 1, SYSDATE - 10, 5, 11, 'Terminada', 'Media', SYSDATE + 20, '', SYSDATE - 1, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (11, 'La feha de revision del proyecto se empalma con la de la junta regional', '', 1, SYSDATE - 9, 5, 11, 'Activa', 'Media', SYSDATE + 45, '', '', '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (12, 'Se requiere incluir seccion para asesores externos', '', 1, SYSDATE - 30, 5, 11, 'Terminada', 'Baja', SYSDATE - 15, '', SYSDATE - 17, '')
/
--
-- Infraestructura interna
--
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (13, 'Se requiere firmar los reportes de salubridad antes de presentarse a gerencia', '', 4, SYSDATE - 145, 1, 4, 'Terminada', 'Media', SYSDATE - 100, '', SYSDATE - 110, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (14, 'Los equipos de refrigeracion no son suficientes para el nivel de comfort aceptable', '', 4, SYSDATE - 45, 1, 9, 'Terminada', 'Alta', SYSDATE - 30, '', SYSDATE - 35, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (15, 'Los contratistas locales no aceptan el pago por medios federales', '', 4, SYSDATE - 90, 1, 10, 'Terminada', 'Alta', SYSDATE - 82, '', SYSDATE - 85, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (16, 'El plan de contingencia en caso de incendio no fue autorizado por el equipo de seguridad de bomberos', '', 4, SYSDATE - 35, 1, NULL, 'Activa', 'Alta', SYSDATE - 5, '', '', '')
/
--
-- Nuevo sistema de nomina
--
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (17, 'Se debe implementar un plan de capacitacion en el cambio de turnos 1 y 2', '', 5, SYSDATE - 8, 2, 5, 'Terminada', 'Media', SYSDATE + 10, '', SYSDATE - 1, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (18, 'El respaldo semanal de la planta Norte excede los limites de ancho da banda aceptables', '', 5, SYSDATE - 100, 2, 12, 'En pausa', 'Media', SYSDATE - 30, 'Ya se solicito la informacion al proveedor de servicio', '', '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (19, 'Se deben transferir los reportes semanales manualmente al servidor hasta que se reestablezca el servicio automatico', '', 5, SYSDATE - 17, 2, 12, 'Terminada', 'Alta', SYSDATE + 4, '', SYSDATE - 4, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (20, 'Prueba del sistema a nivel corporativo pospuesta bajo propuesta de los directores de area', '', 5, SYSDATE, 2, NULL, 'Activa', 'Alta', SYSDATE + 15, '', '', '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (21, 'El reporte de los auditores requiere autorizacion por parte de la direccion', '', 5, SYSDATE - 21, 2, 5, 'Activa', 'Alta', SYSDATE - 7, '', '', '')
/
--
-- Sitio web
--
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (22, 'Revision del esquema de seguridad con los consultores', '', 1, SYSDATE - 60, 4, 7, 'Terminada', 'Alta', SYSDATE - 45, '', SYSDATE - 40, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (23, 'Evaluar propuestas de load balancing contra el presupuesto del proyecto', '', 7, SYSDATE - 50, 4, 7, 'Terminada', 'Alta', SYSDATE - 45, '', SYSDATE - 43, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (24, 'Algunos nombres de dominio seleccionados no estan disponibles', '', 7, SYSDATE - 55, 4, 15, 'Terminada', 'Media', SYSDATE - 45, '', SYSDATE - 50, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (25, 'Establecer politicas para la administracion del sistema en ASP', '', 7, SYSDATE - 20, 4, 16, 'Activa', 'Media', SYSDATE - 5, '', '', '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (26, 'Los servidores proxy estan bloqueando algunas de las herramientas de monitoreo', '', 7, SYSDATE - 10, 4, 15, 'Terminada', 'Alta', SYSDATE - 5, '', SYSDATE - 1, '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (27, 'La fase 1 de las pruebas de stress no puede hacerse sobre la red productiva', '', 7, SYSDATE - 11, 4, 17, 'Activa', 'Alta', SYSDATE, '', '', '')
/
INSERT INTO tareas
            (id_tarea, descrip_corta_tarea, descrip_detallada_tarea, identificada_por, identificada_fecha, proyecto_relacionado, asignada_a, estatus, prioridad, fecha_fin_tentativa, progreso, fecha_fin_real, resumen_solucion)
    VALUES (28, 'Los clientes deben contar con un puerto seguro y los demas puertos deben bloquearse', '', 7, SYSDATE - 20, 4, 17, 'En pausa', 'Alta', SYSDATE, 'En espera del asesor de seguridad, puede llevar un tiempo.', '', '')
/
UPDATE proyectos
SET fecha_inicio = SYSDATE - 150,
    fecha_fin_tentativa = SYSDATE - 30
WHERE id_proyecto = 1
/
UPDATE proyectos
SET fecha_inicio = SYSDATE - 150,
    fecha_fin_tentativa = SYSDATE + 15
WHERE id_proyecto = 2
/
UPDATE proyectos
SET fecha_inicio = SYSDATE - 120,
    fecha_fin_tentativa = SYSDATE - 60
WHERE id_proyecto = 3
/
UPDATE proyectos
SET fecha_inicio = SYSDATE - 60,
    fecha_fin_tentativa = SYSDATE + 30
WHERE id_proyecto = 4
/
UPDATE proyectos
SET fecha_inicio = SYSDATE - 30,
    fecha_fin_tentativa = SYSDATE + 60
WHERE id_proyecto = 5
/
```

Comment: This works just fine for me. That stupid XE browser "interface" is not capable of running more then one statement. Get a proper SQL Client.

Comment: I'd like to but I need to use XE for a school assignment

Comment: Not sure what Apex has to do with this (if anything). What are you using to interact with the database? SQL\*Plus is standard, and it should work just fine with XE; I am not sure what "browser interface" a_horse is referring to, but I used XE in the past with SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer and Toad with no problems (and missed any references to a browser interface, haven't heard of that).

Comment: @mathguy: the "UI" that XE shows in the browser is based on APEX - and is installed e.g. into the start menu in Windows pretending to be the real interface to XE.